# ¿Como puedo abrir una carpeta específica desde un botón en C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una duda que tal vez sea un poco tonta pero que no he podido resolver. Quiero abrir una carpeta específica desde un botón que tengo en mi proyecto de windowsForms en la cual tengo unos excel que se exportaron por un reporte que genera el mismo proyecto. El punto es que quiero que el usuario pueda localizar el archivo sin necesidad de que yo tenga que indicarle la ruta o de que él tenga que buscarla. Para esto yo estoy implementando el botón, el punto es que ya logré abrir documents del usuario pero no la carpeta que necesito que está dentro de la misma. Les dejo aquí mi código:

```
string Ruta = "Export";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", `"%UserProfile%\\Documents\\" + Ruta);`
```

Este se supone me abriría la carpeta de Export pero no, por el contrario lo que hace es abrirme documents y no la carpeta específica que le coloco. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar a solucionar este tema?

Comment: agrega atras las barras, si no lo que esta tratando de abrir es un archivo Export... no sabe que es una carpeta...

Comment: Por favor especifica ¿Cuál es el formato del parámetro: 'ruta'? para establecer algún error de sintaxis.
También te puedo recomendar que uses el comando: 'start'

Comment: ¿Abrir cómo? En el explorador de Windows o te refieres a un diálogo dentro del programa.

Comment: Quiero abrir como tal una ventana de explorador de windows, no dentro de la aplicación si no ejecutar una nueva ventana. Ya intenté poniendo la ruta Export\\ pero no funcionó. Quité el string "ruta" de igual forma poniéndolo directo en el System.Diagnostics.Process.Start como la ruta completa: "%UserProfile%\\Documents\\Export\\" pero de igual forma me sigue abriendo documents y no la carpeta "Export"

Comment: Prueba : Start("%UserProfile%\\Documents\\Export\\") ; Ahora si no te funciona es porque no está expandiendo %UserProfile%. Lee esa variable ,var userprofile=Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UserProfiler"); utiliza esa variable en el start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar esto, la condición es sólo par comprobar que exista la carpeta que quieres abrir. Pero en sí `Process.Start()` es lo que uso

```
string direccion_archivo = "C:/Logs/";

if (Directory.Exists(direccion_archivo))
{
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = direccion_archivo,
        UseShellExecute = true,
        Verb = "open"
    });
}
```

Comment: Hice algunas correcciones que no me validaba correctamente pero la estructura está perfecta. Muchas gracias! así quedó la solición: ` var userprofile = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UserProfile");
            string direccion_archivo = userprofile + "\\Documents\\Export\\";

            if (Directory.Exists(direccion_archivo))
            {
                Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    FileName = direccion_archivo,
                    UseShellExecute = true,
                    Verb = "open"
                });
            } `